# Generate setup.exe for ClickOnce deployment from command line using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

I have a MSBuild script that builds my windows forms application, generates the application manifest and signs it, then generates the deployment manifest. The script also generates the publish.htm file for me.

Now I need to generate the setup.exe file and so far I have not been able to figure out how VS generates it. How can I generate the setup.exe file using a MSBuild script?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What changes with your setup.exe that requires it to be generated with every build?

Comment: I won't necessarily generate it with every build. I intend reusing the script for different applications, so in case of a new application I'd like the script to generate the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in [GenerateBootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx) MSBuild task

When you do a Publish from Visual Studio, this is also what ClickOnce uses.

Check out C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\Microsoft.Common.Targets to see exactly what happens.

Look at the _DeploymentGenerateBootstrapper target.

Your CSharp project file contains some items and properties that this target uses to figure out:

1. If it's going to generate a bootstrapper (BootstrapperEnabled property)
2. The packages to generate the bootstrapper for (BootstrapperPackage item group)
3. Where the packages will be installed from (BootstrapperComponentsLocation property)

Hopefully this makes sense. With a bit of work you can implement with your MSBuild file exactly what happens when you Publish from Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. To workaround it when I got no responses to my question I copied the file generated by visual studio in one of my deployments and reused it. It seemed to work fine, but this task may be what I was looking for. Even if it doesn't solve my problem it's still one more task learned :)

Answer (score 1):

The flags you want to msbuild are:

```
/target:publish
```

and:

```
/p:PublishDir=C:\Foo\
```

Notice that you *must* have a trailing `\` on the publish dir or it simple perform the the dependent steps on publish (ie. build) and never actually generate an installer.

You may be interested in the `msbuild` npm package:

```
var msbuild = require('msbuild');
var path = require('path');

// Config
var source = 'source/Bar/Bar.App/Bar.App.csproj';
var deploy = path.join(__dirname, 'deploy');

// Build the project
var builder = new msbuild();
builder.sourcePath = source;
builder.overrideParams.push('/p:PublishDir=' + deploy + "\\"); // <-- Installer
builder.overrideParams.push('/Target:rebuild;publish');
builder.overrideParams.push('/P:Configuration=Release');
builder.overrideParams.push('/P:verbosity=diag');
builder.overrideParams.push('/P:Platform=x86');
builder.overrideParams.push('/fl');
builder.overrideParams.push('/flp:logfile=build.log;verbosity=diagnostic');
builder.publish();
```

...which you would run something like:

```
npm install msbuild
node builder.js
```

No powershell required.