# Generating a setup.exe (bootstrapper) during deployment

Tags: powershell, clickonce, mage

I'm trying to automate the deployment of a ClickOnce application. The compilation is pretty straight forward (as far as I can tell), however I never see a `setup.exe` get generated. I'm not even sure if the `setup.exe` should be generated at build time, or at deploy time, I'm pretty sure it should be at deployment. (I generate and sign manifests during my deployment so that they're unique per environment `dev/qual/production`)

*note: I've never worked on ClickOnce before, and I haven't developed this project, I'm just tasked with automating it's deployment. If I've missed anything, please ask in the comments.*

**Here's how I compile**

```posh
# https://github.com/transcanada/poshBAR/blob/master/src/poshBAR/MSBuild.ps1#L136
Invoke-CleanMSBuild $this.solutions.uiShell

# https://github.com/transcanada/poshBAR/blob/master/src/poshBAR/MSBuild.ps1#L63
Invoke-MSBuild "$($this.artifactsDir.output)\ClickOnce" `
        $this.solutions.uiShell `
        -target 'package' `
        -toolsVersion 4.0 `
        -maxCpuCount 8 `
        -VisualStudioVersion 12.0 `
        -logPath $this.artifactsDir.logs `
        -namespace 'TransCanada.MCA' `
        -customParameters @('/p:BootstrapperEnabled=true')
```

And here's my csproj file (*excluding dependencies*).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{62B89443-7C08-4753-9C43-F53DABF7549D}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TransCanada.MCA.UI.Shell</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TransCanada.MCA.UI.Shell</AssemblyName>
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <StartupObject>TransCanada.MCA.UI.Shell.ShellApplication</StartupObject>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>true</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>98073FFOOBARBAZFIZZBUZZ19CD2F1A4</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <ManifestKeyFile>
    </ManifestKeyFile>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
    <TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\MCAIcon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Web</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <InstallUrl>http://localhost/</InstallUrl>
    <TargetCulture>en</TargetCulture>
    <ProductName>MCA - Dev</ProductName>
    <PublisherName>TransCanada</PublisherName>
    <MinimumRequiredVersion>0.1.1.1</MinimumRequiredVersion>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>true</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <WebPage>publish.htm</WebPage>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>0.1.1.1</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>true</CreateDesktopShortcut>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>true</CreateDesktopShortcut>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>
    </DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>true</CreateDesktopShortcut>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The solution also has a `customized.targets` file, but I'm not sure if it's even getting picked up.

```xml
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

 <Target Name="UpdateCommonAssemblyInfo">
    <AssemblyInfo  
                    CodeLanguage="CS"
                    OutputFile="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)"
                   AssemblyVersion="$(VersionNum)"
                   AssemblyFileVersion="$(VersionNum)"
                   />
  </Target>


<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildEnvironment>Debug</BuildEnvironment>
</PropertyGroup>

<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(BuildEnvironment)' == 'Debug' ">
      <PropertyGroup>       
        <PublishDir>publish\$(BuildEnvironment)\</PublishDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(BuildEnvironment)' == 'Dev' ">
      <PropertyGroup>       
        <!--<PublishDir>publish\$(BuildEnvironment)\</PublishDir>-->
        <PublishDir>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\MCA\Client\Azure\</PublishDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(BuildEnvironment)' == 'Azure' ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>\\xxxxxxxxxxx\apps\MCA\client\$(BuildEnvironment)\</PublishDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(BuildEnvironment)' == 'Qual' ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>\\xxxxxxxxxxx\cal\APPS\MCA\Client\$(BuildEnvironment)\</PublishDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(BuildEnvironment)' == 'Qual2MatrixProd' ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>\\xxxxxxxxxxx\cal\APPS\MCA\Client\$(BuildEnvironment)\</PublishDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(BuildEnvironment)' == 'Prod' ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>\\xxxxxxxxxxx\cal\APPS\MCA\Client\$(BuildEnvironment)\</PublishDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When> 
</Choose>

<PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Note this must be done AFTER the above Choose (so PublishDir is set)-->
    <PublishFilePath>$(PublishDir)publish.html</PublishFilePath>
    </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
        <Tokens Include="PublisherName">
          <ReplacementValue>$(PublisherName)</ReplacementValue>
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </Tokens>
        <Tokens Include="ProductName">
          <ReplacementValue>$(ProductName)</ReplacementValue>
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </Tokens>
        <Tokens Include="ApplicationVersion">
          <ReplacementValue>$(ApplicationVersion)</ReplacementValue>
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </Tokens>
        <Tokens Include="Prerequsites">
          <ReplacementValue>@(BootstrapperPackage->'&lt;li&gt;%(ProductName)&lt;/li&gt;','%0D%0A')</ReplacementValue>
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </Tokens>
        <Tokens Include="Username">
          <ReplacementValue>$(Username)</ReplacementValue>
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </Tokens>
    </ItemGroup> 
<!--<Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <Time Format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
        <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="PublishTime" />
    </Time>
    <TemplateFile Template="publish\publish.template.html" Tokens="@(Tokens)" OutputFilename="$(PublishFilePath)" />
    <FileUpdate Files="$(PublishFilePath)" Regex="\${PublishTime}" ReplacementText="$(PublishTime)" /> 
</Target> -->
</Project>
```

What am I missing in getting the bootstrapper generated?

Comment: Could be missing the GenerateBootStrapper task? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735788/generate-setup-exe-for-clickonce-deployment-from-command-line-using-msbuild#3852373

Comment: @kev, yeah I've looked at that. The strange thing is that they're *deploy from visual studio* process works.

Comment: I've spent the last two hours trying to get this to work. I truly hate the way that VS hides magic from you like this, such as how the hell it triggers the GenerateBootstrapper task.

Comment: I'm almost at the point of switching to [Squirrel](https://github.com/squirrel/squirrel.windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just manually generate a bootstrapper for each environment through a Visual Studio publish and then be done. Is there a reason why that won't work?

The only reason you'd need to regenerate the bootstrapper is if your prerequisites change or if your application's deployment url changes. Both seem like pretty rare occurrences.

Comment: I've been looking deeper, and I'm thinking I'll only need to gen the setup.exe during the build. Then when I change the configs in different environments, I'm pretty sure I can reuse the setup.exe. Problem is that msbuild isn't generating the setup.exe ATM. Still working through why.

Comment: I'm saying, I don't see the need to have the build generate the setup.exe. The setup.exe doesn't change from build to build. Generate it once with a publish from VS (which you said works) and move on.

Comment: while that's usually true, if during the process of development, a new dependency is added, the setup needs to be re-generated. Manually creating these things fly in the face of devops IMO.

Comment: One more and I'm done - promise :) I'm not a devops hater. I love me some psh scripts. However, I've been working with ClickOnce apps for 10 years. I've never regenerated a setup.exe. If you add a prereq, you'll have bigger issues than regenerating the file. All your existing installs will be broken because the bootstrapper doesn't get re-run when a user launches the app. Nevermind the fact that a lot of pre-reqs require admin privileges which goes against the main reason to use ClickOnce to start with. IMO you're hung up on a issue not worth solving, but maybe you're situation is different.

Comment: I can agree with that. At this point, I'm actually considering scrapping the setup.exe all together since the only dependency is .NET Framework (or maybe switching to squirrel)